# UITextview Hide cursor/Change color of cursor

Tags: iphone, uitextview

In my application, In UITextview i want to hide cursor.

If this is not possible then I want to change color of cursor.

Can we do this? I have search for it but only getting answers for UITextfield.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't specify whether you want to do this while the keyboard is open. I found this because I wanted to do the same thing, but in my case, I didn't have a keyboard open anyway (you can only select the text, not edit it, but this requires editing be enabled). Anyway, the solution for me was simply to `[textView resignFirstResponder];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the cursor only if you disabled the editing property set to No

Answer (score 13):

On iOS 7, you can simply set the tintColor of your text view as the same of its backgroundColor to make the cursor invisible.

```
textView.tintColor = textView.backgroundColor;
```

or you can try:

```
textView.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect, for me, as of iOS 10.3 (unless I'm missing something). Answer below does work.

Answer (score 2):

To hide the cursor, just subclass `UITextField` and override `-caretRectForPosition:` which is implemented by `UITextField` to conform with `UITextInput` protocol:

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    return CGRectZero;    // ensures the cursor won't appear
}
```

<strike>As for changing the color or the cursor, I think it's not possible without accessing private API.</strike>

**EDIT:** as per S. Soffes comment, changing the color is possible via `tintColor` property, obviously.

Comment: You can change the color by setting the text view's `tintColor`.