# Code input text field

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a native UI control for code input text field, for example like Whatsapp:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** To achieve this, they're almost certainly tapping into the [textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a) method for their `UITextField`, selectively accepting and formatting user input to match the dash-if-empty approach.

Further, I'm sure they've subclassed the field; per your comments there isn't a blue cursor - which isn't standard for a `UITextField`.

Comment: any idea how to hide the cursor?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699727/hide-the-cursor-of-an-uitextfield) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525255/uitextview-hide-cursor-change-color-of-cursor) or [this](http://pastebin.com/Gw7dPnJc)...

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. Use a `UITextField`, fill it with dashes, keep track of how many characters the user has entered, and replace the dashes accordingly as the user types.

Comment: it looks more than that, for example there is no blue cursor

Answer (score 1):

There's a 4-digit code input text field called [CodeInputView](https://github.com/acani/CodeInputView) written in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've added a UITextField to the view and set its hidden == true. Then I show/hide the keyboard by calling becomeFirstResponder()/resignFirstResponder() on it. I listen for text did change notifications and update a visible label with the value of the hidden text field.